# How can I apply aop on a whole package except one subpackage

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Assuming my current package structure in a spring projects as :

```
com.stackoverflow
|- service
|- entities
|- controllers
   |- package1
   |- package2
|-util
```

How can I apply an aspect to all the packages under com.stackoverflow except on the package util?

Applying it to everything, the execution expression would be "com.stackoverflow..*.*(..)"

What should the execution expression be in this case I want to remove the util subpackage from the execution expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the AND `&&` and NOT `!` operators in your `Pointcut` expression as

```
@Pointcut ("execution (* com.stackoverflow..*.*(..)) && " +
           "!execution (* com.stackoverflow.util..*.*(..))")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
pointcut="execution(* com.stackoverflow.*.*(..)) && !execution(* com.stackoverflow.util.*.*(..))"
```